# Touchpad works in Gnome, but not KDE

Tags: kde, touchpad

This is on an HP G-61 laptop. Any tips on how to fix the problem? Maverick, but the same problem was there in Lucid ...

I actually just tried this on my MSI Wind, and have the same problem. Basically, I'm installing KDE onto a standard Ubuntu setup using the KDE desktop packages from the repositories, then selecting it manually on the login screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: go to System Settings - Keyboard & Mouse, then go to the touchpad section and set the sensitivity one step next from low

Comment: Well ... it works, although I'm not sure why. The trackpad continues to work most of the way into the startup of KDE without this setting, and then stops. I'm a little curious as to why this works.

Comment: ... and I meant to mention, it does work on both machines that had the problem.